Significance of factors/regressors on compositional data
Let's assume that I have composite data, similar to the "ArcticLake" example dataset in the DirichletReg package in R. Now, I would like to know whether various numeric variables and factors have a significant influence on the distribution of values in these compositional random vectors. Dirichlet regression (as exemplified here: http://r-statistics.co/Dirichlet-Regression-With-R.html) seems to only indicate whether individual components are significantly influenced. However, how can I obtain a p-value to determine whether the distribution of all components (in aggregate) is significantly influenced by the factor?
I guess, I'm looking for an summary(aov())-like output for my compositional data regression.
